# KO Computed field not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm having a shopping cart (http://beta.jcantiques.com/Home/Cart)
You will need to add item from Products page.

I'm unable to get the SUM CBM field working.

[image]

Here is the Code:

> **JS**

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var CartLine = function () {
            var self = this;
            self.UniqueItemCode = ko.observable();
            self.ItemCode = ko.observable();
            self.Description = ko.observable();
            self.SizeInCm = ko.observable();
            self.CmCBM = ko.observable();
            self.Wood = ko.observable();
            self.Quantity = ko.observable();
            self.subtotalCBM = ko.computed(function () {
                return (parseFloat(self.CmCBM) * parseFloat(self.Quantity));
            });
        };

        var Cart = function () {
            var self = this;
            self.lines = ko.mapping.fromJS([]);
            //Converting C# data into JS array
            var orderItems = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))');
            console.log(orderItems);

            // Mapping JS array to KO array
            ko.mapping.fromJS(orderItems, {}, self.lines);

            self.grandTotalCBM = ko.computed(function () {
                var total = 0;
                $.each(self.lines(), function () { total += this.subtotalCBM(); })
                return total;
            });

            self.totalQty = ko.computed(function () {
                var total = 0;
                $.each(self.lines(), function () { total += parseInt(this.Quantity()) })
                return total;
            });

        };
        ko.applyBindings(new Cart());
    });
    </script>
```

> **HTML**

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: lines">
                            <tr>
                                <td><a href="#" class="icon-close remove-item" data-bind="click: $parent.removeLine"><span aria-hidden="true" class="icon_close"></span></a></td>
                                <td>
                                    <img style="width:70px; height:70px;" onerror="if (this.src != '/Content/Images/no_picture.gif') this.src = '/Content/Images/no_picture.gif';" data-bind="    attr: { 'src': '/Content/OPAMS_Images/' + ItemCode + '/' + ItemCode + '-Thumb.jpg' }" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span data-bind="text: ItemCode"></span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span data-bind="text: Description" style="max-width:200px;"></span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span data-bind="text: SizeInCm"></span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span data-bind="text: CmCBM"></span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span data-bind="text: Wood"></span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input data-bind='value: Quantity, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' style="width: 60px;" />
                                    <span class="hidden" data-bind="text: Quantity"></span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span data-bind="text: subtotalCBM"></span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
```

Any help shall be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I viewed your site a bit, you are not using the `CartLine` model you created.

Answer (score 1):

You need to *invoke* the observable in order to read its value:

```
self.subtotalCBM = ko.computed(function () {
    return (parseFloat(self.CmCBM()) * parseFloat(self.Quantity()));
});
```

Comment: Still same. Not computing.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `CartLine` model you created in which handles the computation of `subtotalCBM`.

You are using `ko.mapping` plugin and I dont know if there are *simple* ways to use the `CartLine` model in line with it. But you can use the `create` method of `ko.mapping` to customize the object construction and add the `subtotalCBM` on it.

Like:

```
var mapping = {
  create: function(options) {
     var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data);

     vm.subtotalCBM = ko.computed(function () {
         return (parseFloat(vm.CmCBM()) * parseFloat(vm.Quantity()));
     });

     return vm;
  }
};

// Mapping JS array to KO array
ko.mapping.fromJS(orderItems, mapping, self.lines);
```

Take a look at **Customizing object construction using “create”** section [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) for more info.